# Do squashed pull requests show up in the contributions graph as a single commit?

Tags: github

I'm working on feature branches that can have over a hundred commits over the course of a week or two. I've expected to get daily marks on my contribution graph for these daily commits once my pull request is accepted, but when that pull request gets "Squashed and merged", it looks like it just shows up as a single commit on the contribution graph.

Is this the intended behavior, or are my commits missing for a different reason?

Comment: "squash and merge" by definition means the whole PR is reduced to a single commit (that's the "squash" part). Yes that is intentional, if it's not desired, then don't choose "squash and merge".

Comment: I'm not telling you to change anything, I'm just telling you the result of the merge strategy. If the greenness of a certain dot is more important than the change history of the project, then take whatever action you feel is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they show up as a single commit.  That's because GitHub only counts commits that end up on the default branch, and when you squash a PR, you end up with one commit on the default branch.

I personally don't worry about my contribution graph, so this doesn't matter to me.  However, I also don't use squash and merge, since I write nice, bisectable commits with good commit messages, and squash and merge destroys that.  If it's important to you not to reduce the work that a contributor has made down to a single commit, then you would need a merge strategy whose goal isn't explicitly to destroy history.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is the intended behavior. You only got one commit merged. That's the point of squash and merge.

I do not recommend squash merges. It takes all the carefully considered commit history about how the branch was developed and mashes it into a convenient but homogeneous paste.

> I'm working on feature branches that can have over a hundred commits over the course of a week or two.

I would say this is the real problem. Feature branches should not regularly have over a hundred commits. Your features are too
big, or you're making a lot of commits to fix previous commits, or you have a lot of incidental merge commits from updating your branch, or all of the above.

Update your branch using `rebase` instead of `merge`. `git rebase main` rewrites your branch as if it were written on top of the latest version of main all along. This removes merge commits which say nothing but "I updated my branch" and makes it easier to see what work has been done on the branch. You can change `git pull` to do a rebase instead of a merge with `git pull --rebase` and by default by setting `pull.rebase`. See [`git-config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) and [Git Branching - Rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

Break up large features into a series of smaller features. This is a skill beyond the scope of this answer, but often a big change can be broken down into a series of smaller [refactorings](https://www.refactoring.com/).

Eliminate incidental fixup commits. If you need to fix something in the previous commit, instead of making a new commit "amend" your changes to the previous one with `git commit --amend`.

For a general cleanup, do an interactive rebase and squash your incidental commits individually. Use `fixup`.

```
$ git rebase -i master

pick abcd1234 feature: do that thing
fixup 1234dcba whoops, had a typo in that thing
fixup b33fdead docs: document that thing
fixup afdcefff test: test that thing
fixup deadb33f fix that thing
pick efga1389 feature: did another thing
```

You had six commits, but you only really did two things. Now you will have just two commits for doing two things.

Using these techniques you can bring your PRs down to a handful of well thought out commits, each conveying important information to the reviewer and future developers wondering why the code was written that way.

See [Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) for more.

Comment: well, or you can just make a smaller PR for doing one thing. Easier for people to review it as well

Comment: @maxisam Sometimes, yes, you can accomplish a task in a neat one commit PR, and sometimes solving the issue is too much for one commit. Like fixing a bug (a single issue) might require refactoring code, refactoring tests, fixing tests, writing new tests, fixing code, fixing documentation, fixing code which relied on the bug... each of these is potentially a separate commit. You can turn it into two related PRs, one for preparatory refactoring one for the actual issue, but neither is a one commit PR.

Comment: I agree. I never think this is like a hard rule. In general, we are talking about 80% of cases. And also, it is hard for reviewer with lots of changes anyway.